# How to edit dll with breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a .dll and want to change in code.
but i have no source code can any one.
Please tell me how to get source code from .dll.
and edit code using breakpoints.
I have already tried .net reflector to get source code from .dll file.
but i can't be able to using breakpoints.
Please help if you have any other Option.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular (and best) tool is [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Comment: but i already used reflector please suggest me any other option

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [solution](https://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/) suggested on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325981/can-i-reverse-engineer-my-own-dll).